# Installing Lollipop in unlocked Moto G 1st gen

Tags: motorola-moto-g, android-versions

If I have an unlocked Moto G 1st gen, is there any other way to get Lollipop on it beside waiting for it to show up? My carrier apparently won't update this device in particular.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom recovery installed, you can wipe your device and install CyanogenMod. The latest nightlies are 5.0+. We won't be able to give you a link however, because you didn't let us know where you are located. Which model of the first gen do you have?

Comment: I'm located in mexico. Mine is the 8gb model. What do you mean with custom recovery? Sorry if I ask this, it's the first time I have an android phone so I have no idea.